# How to scrape news articles with (irregular) paragraphs?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-science

sorry for the probably basic question, I a very new to Python and this is my first time posting here.

I am trying to scrape news websites for a data science project at university. Looking through the HTML Code, I found the part that has the actual acticle in it, the path is:

<div data-sara-click-el="body_element" data-area="text" data-pos="1"> <div class="RichText lg:w-8/12 md:w-10/12 lg:mx-auto md:mx-auto lg:px-24 md:px-24 sm:px-16 break-words word-wrap"> <p> [TEXT I AM LOOKING FOR] </p> </div> </div>

The article is apparently split into paragraphs with the data-pos parameter, though there seems to be no logic behind it (in this first article it's data-pos 1, 3, 5 and 6; in another one its 1,2,6 and 7).

How do I account for any data-pos for future articles and how do I add the whole article to my dataframe. With my current code, I only get the very first part of the article:

```
def scrape_test(url):

    titel = soup_test.find("h2").find(class\_="align-middle").text
    autor = soup_test.find(class\_="font-sansUI lg:text-base md:text-base sm:text-s text-shade-dark     dark:text-shade-light mt-8").text
    datum = soup_test.find("time", class\_="timeformat")\["datetime"\]
    inhalt = soup_test.find(attrs={"RichText lg:w-8/12 md:w-10/12 lg:mx-auto md:mx-auto lg:px-24 md:px-24 sm:px-16 break-words word-wrap"}).text



    artikelinformationen = {
        'Titel': [titel],
        'Autor': [autor],
        'Datum': [datum],
        'Artikel': [inhalt]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(artikelinformationen)
    
    return df

df_test = scrape_test(url_test)
print(df_test)'
```

I was trying to get all relevant information (title, author, release time and date and article text) into a dataframe. The first three worked without problems while I only get the first paragraph of the article in the article text.

Comment: Can you share a sample URL?

Comment: @vtasca this is the link for the first article I'm trying to scrape: https://www.spiegel.de/panorama/gesellschaft/berlin-klimaaktivisten-sollen-nach-ber-blockade-fuer-polizeieinsatz-zahlen-a-d9b2c8f4-602e-495f-9e0a-f2743797aaff

Answer (score 1):

You can chain `find()` to get a list of all the paragraphs in the text:

```
body_paragraphs = soup_test.find('div', {'data-area': 'body'}).find_all('div', {'data-sara-click-el': 'body_element'})
```

Then, you can clean the text up a bit and stitch it together:

```
'\n'.join([x.text.strip().replace('\n', '') for x in body_paragraphs])
```

Which will give you what you're looking for (omitting the full article here):

```
Im November haben sich Mitglieder der Letzten Generation auf Rollfelder des Hauptstadtflughafens geklebt, nun sollen sie dafür zahlen. Die Bundespolizei fordert für ihren Einsatz insgesamt 1060 Euro von den Klimaaktivisten.
Die Forderung richtet sich gegen sechs Personen, die an der Aktion der Klimagruppe am 24. November 2022 beteiligt gewesen sein sollen, wie eine Sprecherin der Bundespolizeidirektion sagte. Zuvor hatte die »Berliner Zeitung« berichtet.  Vier Fälle befänden sich in der Vollstreckung, so die Sprecherin. Zwei Aktivisten hätten jedoch Widerspruch gegen den Bescheid eingelegt.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
I've edited the code so it looks like this

`    inhalt = soup_test.find('div', {'data-area': 'body'}).find_all('div', {'data-sara-click-el': 'body_element'})
    '\n'.join([x.text.strip().replace('\n', '') for x in inhalt]) `

Sadly, I can't seem to check the DataFrame if it's working as I get the error message: The variable is not picklable.

Edit: Exporting to csv shows a lot of HTML Code but not the text I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

I know that OP explicitly asked for beautiful soup.

I think that for everybody on stumbling across this question it will be interesting to know about the following python package:

https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper

```
from newspaper import Article

url = 'https://www.spiegel.de/panorama/gesellschaft/berlin-klimaaktivisten-sollen-nach-ber-blockade-fuer-polizeieinsatz-zahlen-a-d9b2c8f4-602e-495f-9e0a-f2743797aaff'

article = Article(url)
article.download()
article.parse()
article.nlp()
```

```
print(article.text)
print(article.summary)
print(article.authors)
```

Comment: While this package certainly seems really useful, it doesn't correctly scrape the entire article either as i leaves out the last paragraph. thanks for the recommendation though!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution myself:

```
 inhalt_elements = soup_spiegel.find_all('div', {'data-area': 'text'})
 inhalt_text = ' '.join([element.get_text(strip=True) for element in inhalt_elements])
```

when joining all information later, use inhalt_text.
Using this, all text in the data area is found and joined with a space.